# Check if any path starting from a vertex in set A and reaching a vertex in set B is long at least k in $\Theta(G)$

Tags: graphs, breadth-first-search

I am trying to verify whether it exists a path from $a \in A$ to $b \in B$ whose length is $\ge k$ in $\Theta(G)$.

This is what I have done:

```
Algo(G,A,b,K)
 Init(G) // colour[v] = WHITE for all v in G.V

 for each a in A do
  if colour[a] = WHITE then
   dist = BFS(G,a)

 for each b in B do
  if colour[b] = BLACK then
   if dist[b] < k then
    return false

 return true;

BFS(G,s)
 for each v in V do
  colour[v] = WHITE
  pred[v] = null
  dist[v] = INFTY
 Q = <s>
 colour[s] = GREY
 while Q is not empty do
  x = Dequeue(Q)
  for each u in Adj[x] do 
   if colour[u] = WHITE then
    Enqueue(Q,u)
    colour[u] = GREY
    pred[u] = x
    dist[u] = dist[x]+1
   colour[x] = BLACK
```

Unfortunately this algorithm is not $\Theta(G)$ but it is $\Theta(V \cdot G)$.
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: By "path" you meant a shortest path?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is solvable within the claimed time bound? Are you sure you copied down the exercise carefully?

Comment: Does the path need to be simple?